# Incorrect syntax into IF... ELSE clause

Tags: t-sql

I have a really simple query like:

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN;
    DECLARE @CurrentPassword VARCHAR(255) = (SELECT TOP 1 [Password] 
                                             FROM Employee 
                                             WHERE @EmpGuid = EmpGuid)
    IF (@Password = @CurrentPassword)
        UPDATE [Employee] 
        SET [Password] = @NewPassword 
        WHERE @EmpGuid = EmpGuid

    SELECT 1;
    ELSE
        SELECT 2;

    COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH
```

But I really don't know why in my `else` clause I get

> Incorrect syntax near 'ELSE'

What am I doing wrong? Regards

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 maybe you should read a bit more on this. "To define a statement block, use the control-of-flow keywords BEGIN and END."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use explicitly `begin . . end`

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN
    DECLARE @CurrentPassword VARCHAR(255) = (SELECT TOP 1 [Password] 
                                             FROM Employee 
                                             WHERE @EmpGuid = EmpGuid)
    IF (@Password = @CurrentPassword)
    BEGIN

        UPDATE [Employee] 
        SET [Password] = @NewPassword 
        WHERE @EmpGuid = EmpGuid

    SELECT 1
    END

    ELSE

    BEGIN
        SELECT 2
    END

    COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 1):

You you want to have *more than one* statement after the `IF`, you **must use** a `BEGIN .... END` block - like this:

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN;
    DECLARE @CurrentPassword VARCHAR(255) = (SELECT TOP 1 [Password] 
                                             FROM Employee 
                                             WHERE @EmpGuid = EmpGuid)
    IF (@Password = @CurrentPassword)
    BEGIN     --- you need a *BEGIN* here!!!
        UPDATE [Employee] 
        SET [Password] = @NewPassword 
        WHERE @EmpGuid = EmpGuid

        SELECT 1;
    END        --- and the *END* for your new *BEGIN*
    ELSE
        SELECT 2;

    COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH
```